# getting 500 error code and cross origin while sending token in header in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While I am calling get request in `axios` I am sending the token in header but token is displaying `null` in backend and giving error like 500 and cross origin error:

```
 var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

 axios.get("http://x.x.x.x:8080/entity-services/api/v1/user?isActive=true", {headers: {
            "auth_key" : token
          }
        })
```

this is error showing in console;

> OPTIONS http://x.x.x.x:8080/entity-services/api/v1/user?isActive=true
>   500
>       Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/entity-services/api/v1/user?isActive=true' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access contro

Comment: Before browser sends the GET request it will send a preflight using OPTIONS, check your devtools and see if the OPTIONS request is missing required headers.

Comment: Server should allow `GET` request and send proper response

Comment: What kind of back-end server are you using ?

Comment: spring rest full services

Comment: @Cray
 Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: x.x.x:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: auth_key
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Cross Origin Resource sharing. Just add following header in you response headers in you backend and it should work:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: Can you add the backend code where you have added it  ?

Comment: check is you are getting token from localStorage or not ? `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));`

Comment: ,yes i am getting token ,but while sending the request to backend ,in backend token is showing null .